# How to connect strings crossing lines in bash?

Tags: bash

In script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Above is a while statement, so the printf has a indent(actually are 3 spaces)
   printf "I am a too long sentence in line1, I need to switch to a new line. \n\
   I'd like to be at the head of this line2, but actually there are 3 redundant spaces \n"
```

As I said in the code, it shows:

```
I am a too long sentence in line1, I need to switch to a new line.
      I'd like to be at the head of this line2, but actually there are 3 redundant spaces
```

To solve the problem, I have to use a `printf` in each line. Like:

```
   printf "I am a too long sentence in line1, I need to switch to a new line. \n"
   printf "I'd like to be at the head of this line2, but actually there are 3 redundant spaces \n"
```

I think it's too stupid, is there any why to connect strings like below?

```
   printf {"a\n"
   "b"}

   # result should be like below
a
b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `printf` the way it is generally used. The first string defines the format and the following strings are the arguments.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
   printf '%s\n' "I am a too long sentence in line1, I need to switch to a new line."\
      "I'd like to be at the head of this line2, but actually there are 3 redundant spaces."\
            "I don't care how much indentation is used"\
 "on the next line."
```

Output:

```
I am a too long sentence in line1, I need to switch to a new line.
I'd like to be at the head of this line2, but actually there are 3 redundant spaces.
I don't care how much indentation is used
on the next line.
```

Comment: In my example the `\n` is in the format string. But you could use `%b` instead of `%s\n` to interpret escape sequences. Like `printf '%b' "line one\n" "line two\nand three\n"`.

Comment: How could I add a new \n to a specific line please? Take your code as an example, I'd like add a new blank line bewteen line1 and line2. I tried add "\n" to the end of line1 sentence but not working.

Comment: See my comment above ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Freddy's method is based on the prinf. And I found a common way to just build a string with multiple lines and indent free:

```
#!/bin/bash
concat() {
  local tmp_arg
  for each_arg in $@
  do
    tmp_arg=${tmp_arg}${each_arg}
  done
  echo ${tmp_arg}
}

# indent free
   str=$(concat "hello1\n" \
   "hello2\n" \
   hello3)
   printf $str"\n"
```

The result:

```
hello1
hello2
hello3
```

Answer (score 0):

@Anon The solution to your problem is actually very simple. You can either use the function method or single lash method also works for multi-line comment without using printf on each line.

**Solution:**

```
echo "This is the first line. " \
> "This is second line"
```

**Output:**

```
This is first line. This is second line
```

You can use this method to connect multiple strings in single echo command. Using slash you will get second blank line where you can add new sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Within quotes you can add line feeds. In other words, quotes don't need to be closed on the same line, so you can have multi-line strings without even a continuation character. Try this:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "This text has
several lines.
This is another
sentence."

         echo "This line is printed starting from the left margin
    and these lines
    are indented
    by four spaces"

printf "This text contains
not %d, but %d two substitution
fields.\n" 1 2
```

which yields

```
This text has
several lines.
This is another
sentence.
This line is printed starting from the left margin
    and these lines
    are indented
    by four spaces
This text contains
not 1, but 2 two substitution
fields.
```

Comment: How could your solution handle the indentation if the line is within a loop or if construction which may brings several redundant spaces. For example, there is a line behinde 4 spaces indentation and autoindent is open in vim (I'd like my code clear to read by indent) "wget https://iamatoooooooooooooooolongcommand.com/toooooooolong.gz", this is such a long command, and I want part of it switch to a new line ,which have to also behind the indent,to read instead of scroll it horizontally with vim.

Comment: Bash reads the lines as is, so the first character after the opening quite is print in column1. For the next lines, it considers the line starting from column 0. See example in edited answer.